# How are the semi-transparent blur windows in OSX and W10 Start Menu created?

Tags: c#, wpf, blur

I'm currently working on a window that focuses on some elements on screen while blurring the rest of the area.

Using common methods like the [WindowCompositionAttribute](http://withinrafael.com/adding-the-aero-glass-blur-to-your-windows-10-apps/) and the others are not suitable for this situation as there are limitations to it and it doesn't meet the standards regarding the intensity of the blur, contrast and colors which should be strict.

What i have managed to solve my problem was building an image stream with a light image encoder to enhance performance but then that wasn't enough. So, i thought of writing a motion detection algorithm to only steam when there's motion, but it still didn't change the performance drops.

What i need is something like those of the native OSX windows and Windows 10 Start Menu, so how are they created and run efficiently without any heavy load on the performance?

Answer (score 0):

To create a new Window from scratch you have to set *WindowsStyle* to none (*AllowTransparency="True"* can be set only along with *WindowsStyle="None"*)  and from there build the style of the window.
However, you will face several issues if you follow this approach:
-no buttons (minimize, close)
-no support for fullscreen (taskbar issues)

I would suggest you to have a base view and include the other views inside the main view(which has the blur effect).
The blur effect could be obtained easily by doing something like below:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid Margin="5" Background="#FF3782DC">
            <!--<Grid.Background>
                <Image Source="test.png"></Image>
            </Grid.Background>-->
            <Grid.Effect>
                <BlurEffect Radius="100" />
            </Grid.Effect>
        </Grid>
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="textBlock"
            Height="61"
            Margin="136,82,211,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Text="test"
            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </Grid>
```

I've set a color for the background, but you could set an image as background and by default it would be blurred (here you should set a binding and every time the view changes, you have to take a snapshot of the screen and set the source of the Image). However you will probably have some performance issues, but with a good encoder (JPEGencoder) it will be fast enough.

Hope that helps you!